# Put two or three images in one round shape in IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I am trying to get two images of users each in semicircle of circle here in this shape but havent succeeded, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the exact solution, but you can look into `mask` of `UIImageView`. Use two `UIImageVIew`s and set mask for each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code may be helpful for you
    _imgViewProfile=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,44,44)];
    [_imgViewProfile.layer setCornerRadius:_imgViewProfile.bounds.size.width/2];
    _imgViewProfile.clipsToBounds = YES;

In order to make the circle your uiImageview's height and width should be equal.